# How to scrape the starting MLB lineups into Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I am new to scraping and still learning. What is the best way to parse the MLB starting lineups into a Pandas DataFrame using Python?

Here is my attempt at a scrape here:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.baseballpress.com/lineups'
headers = {'User-Agent':
           'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

df = pd.read_html(url)

print(df)
```

I received the an error:

```
ValueError: No tables found
```

There is 1 pitcher and 9 batters listed for each team, and 2 teams for each game (so 20 players total per game).

Here is an example of the output that I am looking for each team:

```
Seth Lugo

Brandon Nimmo
Michael Conforto
J.D. Davis
Dominic Smith
Robinson Cano
Pete Alonso
Jeff McNeil
Andres Gimenez
Robinson Chirinos
```

Here is a pic of the data:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help that you may offer. Much appreciated. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, You used a wrong link (if you consider the image attached) to scrape data from there. Secondly, although the content in there seem to be within tables, there is no `tr` or `td` tag associated with them. Moreover, you can't grab all the player names if you use `html.parser`. You can fetch all them using `lxml` or `html5lib` parser, though. So, this is one of the ways you can get them.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.baseballpress.com/lineups/2020-09-17"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
for item in soup.select("[data-league='NL']:contains('Mets') .player > a.player-link"):
    player_name = item.get('data-razz').split("/")[-2].replace("+"," ")
    print(player_name)
```

Try the following to get the lineups accordingly:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.baseballpress.com/lineups/2020-09-17"

def get_names(item):
    try:
        player_name = item.get('data-razz').split("/")[-2].replace("+"," ")
    except IndexError: player_name = ""
    return player_name

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
first_lineup = [get_names(item) for item in soup.select(".col--min:nth-of-type(1) > a.player-link, [class$='col--min']:nth-of-type(1) .player > a.player-link")]
second_lineup = [get_names(item) for item in soup.select(".col--min:nth-of-type(2) > a.player-link, [class$='col--min']:nth-of-type(2) .player > a.player-link")]

df = pd.DataFrame({"first_lineup":first_lineup,"second_lineup":second_lineup})
df.to_csv("baseballpress.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: Ty sir @SIM for your help and explantion! Can you please explain why you chose to use 'lxml' and why that worked? Also, I was hoping to get the lineups for each team. I noticed that the code contains 'Mets' only. Any suggestions how to get all of the players on each team?

Comment: Also, it looks like some of the names double printed.

Comment: I used the word `Mets` only to identify the data in your attached image. To get all the players, you should kick out this `[data-league='NL']:contains('Mets')` portion and stick with the rest. The reason why I used `lxml` can be found [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser). In short it has the capability to fix broken tags. Thanks.

Comment: So amazing @SIM! Thank you so much for your help. Very impressive. I will learn a lot from this. =)